# Java asynchronously wait x seconds

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

To give some details about what I'm trying to do: I'm making a Minecraft plugin in Java. I have an Object which is bound to the Player object of Minecraft using a HashMap.

I have a method in this object which is something like:

```
    public void faint() {
        ... //Apply the effect on the player

        //wait for x seconds, and if the player didn't already wake up, wake them up. (player.wakeUp())
    }
```

Obviously, there will be a lot of stuff going on, so I want this to happen asynchronously. The timer will go on in the background and it won't block anything else in the code.

Sorry if my question is too simple, but I really checked the web and I'm new to Java, so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: 'Asynchronous wait' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Bukkit scheduler](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html).

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(yourPluginInstance, () -> {
    // put code here to run after the delay
}, delayInTicks);
```

When the code runs after the delay it will run on the main server thread.

Comment: Shouldn't I use "runTaskLaterAsynchronously" instead? Thank you so much, by the way.

Comment: No, only use runTaskLaterAsynchronously if you want the code to run asynchronously after the delay. You most likely want the code to run on the main server thread after the delay which is what runTaskLater does (the main server thread is not blocked during the delay).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate thread by implementing a `Runnable` interface like this and do the delay in there.

```
// This is happening in the main thread
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      // This code will run async after you execute
      // thead.start() below
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Time to wake up");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // See https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056-Shutting-down-Threads-Cleanly.html
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }

thread.start();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't try this in action yet, but I think it will! I will inform in here if this works.

Comment: Cool. If this also solves your problem, please upvote the answer, so its easier for others to find it and reuse it in their work.

Comment: I don't have 15 "reputation" therefore I can't upvote lol, but I did press upvote; which will impact the priority of your answer (at least that's what stackoverflow says).

Comment: The correct solution is to use the Bukkit scheduler. Also you most likely want the code after the delay to run on the main server thread so you have to use the Bukkit scheduler anyways.

Comment: But what would be the point? The thread runs, sleeps, exits: nobody else knows anything about it.